# getting the holder of an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a Course class which has a method to add Items, which can be a note, an assignment, a URL, or just a generic item. All Items are kept in an ArrayList which the Course that created the list keeps up with. My question is from an item inside this ArrayList, how do I get the printLogger that I have attached to the course object in order to attach it to an item when the Item is created?

this from my Course:

```
public class Course {
private ArrayList<Item> items;
public PrintLogger p1 = null;

public Course(String code, String name) {
 this.code = code;
 this.name = name;
 items = new ArrayList<>();
}

void add(Item item) {
 items.add(item);
 if (hasPrintLogger() == true) {
  log(PrintLogger.INFORMATIONAL, "Adding " + item.toString());
 }
}
```

And Im trying to have in the code that the assignment constructor runs a way to attach the same printLogger that is already on the course.

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: please edit your question with the relevant code

Comment: The printlogger originates in the course class because thats where we initially had to create the print logger. now we have to add it to the assignment class (child class of item).

Answer (score 0):

You could store a reference to the proper `Course` object in each of the items in the `List`.

You could also wrap the `ArrayList` class in your own class and add a field that points to the `Course` it belongs to if you need it to be a relationship between the `List` and the `Course` instead of between the items in the `List` and the `Course`.

You could also search each `Course` object in your system and check if it contains the `List` in question. However, this solution would scale badly.